# IBM Mobilefirst 8.0 WLAuthorizationManager.login throws "LOGIN_ALREADY_IN_PROGRESS" after window.location.reload() in cordova app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins, mobilefirst-auth

Hi I am using WLAuthorizationManager for the authentication in my application, the app works perfectly fine for the first time i have code to reload the app using "$window.location.reload" after my user logs out of my application.

The problem arrises after logout , i do a logout perfectly via "WLAuthorizationManager.logout" and after successful logout i am trying to login again.

This time it show me "LOGIN_ALREADY_IN_PROGRESS" error. But it works fine when i close my application and login again.

I tried using document.location.realod and also WL.Client.reloadApp everything results same.

Comment: In which environment you facing this issue ? Can you provide issue re-creatable sample?

Comment: i am facing in the android environment and i haven't tested in IOS.

Comment: The message comes when you try login multiple times- Can you verify your code to see if you hit the login too soon - before logout completes. Or if there is a possibility of multiple login calls made OR , you have started login, but your are also requesting a protected resource

Comment: @VivinK if what you are saying is true i should not be able to access when i logout without reloading the app, but that works fine if i don't reload the app via "$window.location.reload" everything works fine , if i reload it the error starts coming.

Comment: I am making an observation. So from your own statement it works fine when you are not reloading. May be there is a race condition in your code that is causing it. Share a recreatable sample.